# Fade in and out word in sentence for one loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have been trying to get one word in a sentence from an HTML page to go through one loop of changing. I only want it to loop once but now that I have gotten the code to loop once I can not see the words.

I used jQuery to make it fade in and out and I know it is incrementing, they just do not appear on the screen from the array. The first and last words appear but nothing from the array in between.

I have found ways to make a never ending loop with the array but I want it to stop once it reaches the last index and stay on one word after that.

Any help or idea for another way to solve this is super welcome.

```css
#changeMainText{
    color: #34495E;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.hide{
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <h1>I am <span id="changeMainText" style="color:#34495E">a Product
    Manager</span>.</h1>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mainText = ["a Programmer", "a Web Developer", "a Student"];
    var counter = -1;
    var textInterval;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeMainText");
    var elem1 = "-1";
    textInterval = setInterval(changeText(counter), 2500);

    function changeText(counter) {
        elem.classList.add('hide');
        setTimeout(function() {
            elem.innerHTML = mainText[counter];
            elem.classList.remove('hide');
            counter = counter + 1;
            document.getElementById("changeMainText").style
                .color = "#34495E";
            if (counter < mainText.length) {
                elem.innerHTML = mainText[counter];
                changeText(counter);
            }
            if (counter == 3) {
                document.getElementById("changeMainText").style
                    .color = "red";
                elem.innerHTML = "a Person";
                clearInterval(textInterval);
            }
        }, 2500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit confusing. And can be simplified quite a bit. You start with `$( document ).ready( function () {} );` but then don't use `jQuery` after. If you're using `jQuery` let it help you.

```js
var loopText = [
  'a Product Manager',
  'a Programmer',
  'a Web Developer',
  'a Student'
];
var i = 0;
var max = loopText.length;
var $text = $('#swap-text');
var css = {};

// Immediately Invoked Named Function Expression - we define it then
// immediately call it by the parenthesis after the closing bracket,
// function (){}(). Once it has done it's work we call it again with
// `setTimeout()` as long as our counter `i` is not equal to the 
// number of entries in the `loopText` array.
(function changeText() {

  if (i < max) {

    if (i === (max - 1)) {
      css['color'] = 'red';
    }

    $text
      .fadeOut(0)
      .text(loopText[i++])
      .css(css)
      .fadeIn(500);

    setTimeout(changeText, 2500);

  }

}());
```

```css
#swap-text {
  color: #34495E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>I am <span id="swap-text"></span>.</h1>
```

Comment: Thank You! That works perfectly and makes much more sense now. I am new to Jquery so I am still trying to get the grasp of things!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your `css` :

```
 .hide{
    opacity: 0 !important;
  }
```

the opacity is not allowing the text to be displayed. Try removing it or changing it to `opacity: 1`

if you're looking for fade in or fade out effect you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mainText = ["a Programmer", "a Web Developer", "a Student","a Person"];
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeMainText");

 function repeat(i){
    if (i<mainText.length){
       setTimeout(function(){
          $(elem).fadeOut('slow').html(mainText[i]).fadeIn('slow');i++
            repeat(i);
       },2500);
    }
}

repeat(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you're setting an interval that runs every 2.5 seconds. The first thing that function does is hide `elem`. Then it sets a timeout to set the text and show the `elem` 2.5 seconds later. Which is when the next interval is scheduled to run, which immediately applies the `hide` class.

I would recommend getting rid of the interval all together, and taking a step back to look at your problem. Here's a lousy ascii art flow diagram thing that describes what I believe you're trying to implement:

```
initial state -> hide -> change text -> show -> next? --no-> stop playing
                   ^----------------------yes----/
```

So, I think you need two functions; one that changes the text and enables `elem` for display, and one that checks if it's okay to move on to the next element of the array and acts accordingly.

```
function changeTextAndShow() {
    // set the text with the current position
    elem.innerHTML = mainText[counter];

    // funny stuff
    if(counter == mainText.length - 1) {
        document.getElementById("changeMainText").style
            .color = "red";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("changeMainText").style
            .color = "#34495E";
    }
    // show the elem
    elem.classList.remove('hide');

    // schedule the next change
    counter++;
    setTimeout(continueText, 2500);    
}

function continueText() {
    // if there's more text to display
    if(counter < mainText.length) {
        elem.add('hide');
        // being blank for 2.5s might not be what you want.
        // change this to the duration you really want it empty
        setTimeout(changeTextAndShow, 2500);
    }
}
```

And then to use it it would be something like:

```
var mainText = ["a Programmer", "a Web Developer", "a Student", "a Person"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeMainText");
setTimeout(continueText, 2500);
```